# Vaadin grid save edited item issue

Tags: java, vaadin7

I'm having some problems when I use Vaadin's Grid with BeanItemContainer. It displays a row OK, but when I try to save edited row it throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given item id (uz.sample.backend.entity.MyBean@4d949367) does not exist in the container
    at com.vaadin.ui.Grid$AbstractSelectionModel.checkItemIdExists(Grid.java:1367)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Grid$SingleSelectionModel.select(Grid.java:1457)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Grid$SingleSelectionModel$1.select(Grid.java:1442)
```

Then if I click again save button it throws:

```
com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup$CommitException: Property "organConductedCourse" not bound to datasource.
    at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup.startTransactions(FieldGroup.java:557)
    at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup.commit(FieldGroup.java:476)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Grid.saveEditor(Grid.java:6817)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Grid$4.save(Grid.java:4782)
```

My code something like this:

> ```
> Grid grid = new Grid();
> grid.setSizeFull();
> grid.setEditorEnabled(true);
> BeanItemContainer<MyBean> container = new BeanItemContainer<>(MyBean.class);
> container.addBean(new MyBean());
> grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
> ```

I don't know where I'm doing wrong. Maybe you have any idea. Thanks for any advise!

Comment: I found an answer after some searching again. I had to use BeanContainer instead of BeanItemContainer. It turns out that BeanItemContainer uses the hashCode of each Item to identify the item.  So, MyBean's hashCode() is based on a field that is changed after edited. Then item was not found and "item id does not exist in the container" error was throwed.

Comment: Your comment really helped me thank you

Comment: Same here.  +1.  I didn't even think of looking at the HashCode for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer after some searching again. I had to use `BeanContainer` instead of `BeanItemContainer`. It turns out that `BeanItemContainer` uses the hashCode of each Item to identify the item. So, `MyBean`'s `hashCode()` is based on a field that is changed after edited. Then item was not found and "item id does not exist in the container" error was thrown.(as nobody answered to this question, I took my comment that is a solution as the answer, I hope it will help others)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to still use the BeanItemContainer by editing my hashCode()-Method to use two identifiers I have on my Objects. You just solved three ours of debugging. You made my day!